# Sql Server: Execute delete against updateable view with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

In SQL it is possible to run inserts and updates against a view, as long as the view only selects data from one table. However, deletes don't seem to work quite so well. Can anyone help out?

Take this view for example:

```
CREATE VIEW v_MyUpdatableView
AS
    SELECT x.* FROM MyPrimaryTable x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AnotherTable y ON y.MyPrimaryTableId = x.Id
```

I can run updates and inserts against this view and they happily pass through to MyPrimaryTable.
However, if I run a delete I receive the following exception:

> View or function 'v_MyUpdatableView' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a stored procedure that would delete the data from two tables. I know it's not pretty, but it would work or do logical deletes, where you update a column to be "deleted".

Answer (score 2):

Quote:

> DELETE statements remove data in one or more of the member tables through the partitioned view. The DELETE statements **must** adhere to this rule:
>
> - DELETE statements are not allowed if there is a self-join with the same view, or any of the member tables.

[Data Modification Rules - Creating a Partitioned View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141%28SQL.80%29.aspx)